# How can I count the number of zeros in all columns for a table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count, multiple-columns, zero

Suppose you have a database table named db_table1 with hundreds of columns and most of them contain lots of 0's.

I'm trying to count zeros for each column and divide it by the length of column so I can see the ratio of zeros in each column.

The below code gives me the ratio of nulls in each column. But I couldn't revise it to count 0's instead of nulls

Any help will be appreciated

```
SELECT column_name, (num_nulls/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_table)*100)
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name='table’
```

Sample data:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| 0.000 | 0.000 | 14.857 |
| 3.548 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| 0.000 | 11.586 | 0.000 |

Expected Output:

| All_Columns | Ratio_of_Zeros |
| --- | --- |
| col_1 | 65.5 |
| col_2 | 73.5 |
| col_3 | 48.6 |

Briefly I need the total number of zeros in every column divided by total row number which gives me the percent or ratio of zeros in each column so I can treat zeros like null and eliminate the column if it has more than 60 percent zeros lets say...

Comment: Please can you provide some example data and expected result from that data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
WITH AA AS (
select 
col_1,col_2,col_3
from table_name
)

SELECT column_name, COUNT(column_name) zeros FROM
(
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT * FROM AA
UNPIVOT(
    zeros  
    FOR column_name 
    IN ( 
col_1,col_2,col_3
    )
)
) WHERE zeros = 0
) GROUP BY column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT 'SELECT ''' || table_name || ''' AS table_name, ' ||
               '''' || column_name || ''' AS column_name, ' ||
               '100 - SUM(LENGTH(REPLACE(TO_CHAR("'|| column_name || '", ''fm999999999999999990.000''), ''0''))-1)' ||
               ' / SUM(LENGTH(TO_CHAR("'|| column_name || '", ''fm999999999999999990.000''))-1) * 100 AS ratio_of_zeroes ' ||
       'FROM "' || table_name || '" UNION ALL'
       column_name
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  data_type = 'NUMBER';
```

To generate an SQL statement and remove the `UNION ALL` from the last line and execute it.

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col_1, col_2, col_3) AS
SELECT 0.000,  0.000,  0.000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0.000,  0.000, 14.857 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3.548,  0.000,  0.000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0.000,  0.000,  0.000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0.000,  0.000,  0.000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0.000, 11.586,  0.000 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the statement generated (with the final `UNION ALL` removed) is:

```sql
SELECT 'TABLE_NAME' AS table_name, 'COL_1' AS column_name, 100 - SUM(LENGTH(REPLACE(TO_CHAR("COL_1", 'fm999999999999999990.000'), '0'))-1) / SUM(LENGTH(TO_CHAR("COL_1", 'fm999999999999999990.000'))-1) * 100 AS ratio_of_zeroes FROM "TABLE_NAME" UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE_NAME' AS table_name, 'COL_2' AS column_name, 100 - SUM(LENGTH(REPLACE(TO_CHAR("COL_2", 'fm999999999999999990.000'), '0'))-1) / SUM(LENGTH(TO_CHAR("COL_2", 'fm999999999999999990.000'))-1) * 100 AS ratio_of_zeroes FROM "TABLE_NAME" UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE_NAME' AS table_name, 'COL_3' AS column_name, 100 - SUM(LENGTH(REPLACE(TO_CHAR("COL_3", 'fm999999999999999990.000'), '0'))-1) / SUM(LENGTH(TO_CHAR("COL_3", 'fm999999999999999990.000'))-1) * 100 AS ratio_of_zeroes FROM "TABLE_NAME";
```

And the output of executing that is:

> | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | RATIO_OF_ZEROES |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | TABLE_NAME | COL_1 | 83.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 |
> | TABLE_NAME | COL_2 | 80 |
> | TABLE_NAME | COL_3 | 80 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=853d170140d55819a8f4e51197ff9ddd)*

Comment: thanks a lot but there're more than 200 columns in the table :)

Comment: @BuğraBalantekin That should not make any difference.